# Windows 10 Mail forgets Gmail password almost every day

Tags: windows-10, gmail, windows-mail

I use Windows 10 (Enterprise 1703) and logged in to Mail app with my @live.com and @gmail.com accounts.

My live.com account just works well, but my gmail forgets password almost every day.

I get a message stating "your gmail settings are out of date", if I go to fix it I need just to enter my password and I'm logged in again.
It also contains [this link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/your-account-settings-are-out-of-date-in-mail-or-calendar-for-windows-10-4484de9e-66b2-46a9-8459-6ca1fcc110b4?wt.mc_id=WMail_AcctStgsErr_Learn&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) but I couldn't find anything useful there.

Although it doesn't take many time it's just annoying, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

### Reason

Windows Mail app keeps prompting for Gmail account password frequently with the "***your gmail settings are out of date***" message—
According to a comment on [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-callmsg-winpc/gmail-keeps-sending-to-me-your-gmail-settings-are/92ea226d-8a11-4b3d-aea9-f6ec2a4e7521) . . .

> [**RayMulder**](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/7c8951d8-25c7-49df-9ca3-85c898c9f90b) replied on  August 4, 2016
>
> "The actual reason for this is that Gmail won't let you in from
>   Windows 10 because Windows uses a less secure method."

---

### Potential Solutions

Based on some quick research there may be two options that may help resolve this. . .

1. Enable the [2-Step Verification](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome) functionality and security feature with your [Gmail](https://gmail.com) account and then use the **2-Step Verification** to verify and trust the **Windows Mail** app to have access to your **Gmail** account
2. Enable and use the [Less Secure Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) functionality by turning that **ON** and using your usual [Gmail](https://gmail.com) account password with the **Windows Mail** app to authenticate

---

### Further Resources

- [Turn on 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839)

  - [Apps with access to your account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)
- [Sign in using App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)

  - [App passwords - My Account - Google](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)

    > App passwords let you sign in to your Google Account from apps on
    >   devices that don't support 2-Step Verification. You'll only need to
    >   enter it once so you don't need to remember it.
- [Let less secure apps access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Comment: Thanks! I've turned on 2 step verification, will see whether I stay signed in.

Comment: something similar is happening to me but in this case its the Google Drive File Stream client that keeps forgetting its credentials. I Wonder if the issues are related, I think auth happens in a "web view" behind the scenes for the OAuth2 dance to take place with js. Pretty sure its MS edge implementing this web view screwing it in ways neither chrome or firefox do. Just like the good old days of webdev :(

Comment: Yeah but only use "less secure apps" only if you're forced to like when using a pop client from a feature phone resurrected from the 90s or something, as those "application passwords" grant full access to your whole Google account, rendering 2FA or any other efforts useless. Those "application passwords" are more powerful than your own password. Even if you get paranoid and change your password often, unless you explicitly revoke an "application password" it will still authenticate and grant access to anyone using it on any service that takes them. That means almost all services that matter.

Comment: Yup. Google's 2FA is enterprise class with and even have an option to use SMS, OTPs, an app generating time-based tokens or even a hardware yubikey, all for free (except the yubikey hardware) now, with the login prompt on mobile devices, there's no excuse not to use it. FB's or Twitter's login codes are a joke, and not a very funny one

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: yes, two factor authorization worked for three days but yesterday also that dropped me and I was nor even able to login without removing my account and adding it back. I'm waiting for it now how it'll work. Setting windows mail as less secure app doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: it's a company laptop, unfortunately it's not my decision when I'll update it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I removed all my old comments but on **Windows 10 version 1803** I still have not had any issue and I've had it up and running around 3 weeks now and have not been prompted once with the 2FA configuration. I can only assume MS patched the Windows Mail app bug you are experiencing with something released after your version and whatever patches are installed on it level wise. If you ever get a chance to get it updated to 1803 though, I would love to hear back from you if that resolved the problem as I cannot recreate it otherwise.

Comment: I've updated to Windows 10 1709 (as it's a work pc it's not my decision when to update and to which version) two weeks ago and the issue is still the same.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Wow.... yeah, I understand and no worries.... Just note I've only verified on **Windows 10 1803**. Thanks for the follow up. I'll be curious of your results when you get to 1803 too.

Answer (score 0):

I had set up my Gmail account in an app used to access my Yahoo At&t email. When I went to look at my yahoo email from Currently.Com.mail, I noticed that my Gmail account was also set up in the app and I was logged out.

I deleted my Gmail account from the Currently app, and it seems the error message to fix the Gmail login issue in Windows 10 Mail has disappeared.